# Formatting numbers in JS

Tags: javascript, string, numbers

I'd like to display numerical information to users in a flexible way. `toFixed` and `toPrecision` always pad with zeros, which is undesirable. Ideally, I would be able to express that:

- 5.450000000001 should be displayed as "5.45"
- 6.0 should be displayed as "6"
- 5.45001 should be displayed as "5.45001", but I'd also like to explicitly say "use no more than 2 decimal places", in which case this should be displayed as "5.45".

Are there good JS libraries for displaying numbers this way? If not, is there a good library in some other language that I can translate?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want two decimal spaces unless the number ends in a `0`. If it ends in a `0` you want the remove the trailing `0`. Right?

Comment: Check http://numeraljs.com/

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't need a whole library for this one purpose. For example, you could just use `toFixed(2)` and then strip trailing `0`s and a trailing decimal point:

```
function format_number(x){
  return ((+x).toFixed(2)+'').replace(/\.?0*$/, '');
}
```

Usage:

```
format_number(5.450000000001); // "5.45"
format_number("6.0"); // "6"
format_number("5.45001"); // "5.45"
```

It would be easy to accept the maximum number of decimal points as an optional argument too:

```
function format_number(x, digits){
  if(typeof digits != 'number')
    digits = 2;
  return ((+x).toFixed(digits)+'').replace(/\.?0*$/, '');
}

format_number(5.45001); // "5.45"
format_number(5.45001, 5); // "5.45001"
```

Comment: Could the downvoter kindly leave a comment, so that I can improve my answer?

Comment: Here's a way to do it with one regex: http://jsbin.com/oTUpUXI/1/edit. Seems to work fine, but may need some adjustments.

Comment: ```316245753745765473542543257.toFixed(4) // =>
'3.162457537457655e+26'```